# Extract Date from HTML page using regex in R language

Tags: html, r, regex

How do I extract just the date in **title="11:53 AM - 27 May 2018"** using REGEX.

FYI this is from a HTML page. I want to extract all such matches to a list using R language.

My output should be  27 May 2018.

Thanks in advance for your time :)

Comment: I think you should be using a DOM parser to extract the `title` attribute.  After this, you might also use a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you have HTML code of the page in which you want to find the date, the simplest way will be to use regex to find all parts of the code that look like 
`title="11:53 AM - 27 May 2018"`
Then you can simply again use regex to extract the date from the string.
I have written a basic code, you can modify it and use it according to your nee.

```
first_match <- regexpr(pattern='title\\s*=\\s*"\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\s*(AM|PM)\\s*-\\s*\\d\\d\\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{4}"', str)`
match_str <- regmatches(str,m)
date_exp <- regexpr(pattern='\\d\\d\\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{4}', match_str)
date <- regmatches(match_str, date_exp)
```

date is your required output and str is the code as string.

Comment: `sub(".*-","",your_string)` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
rawHTML <- paste(readLines("D:\\practicum\\CSK.html"), collapse="\n")

b<-unlist(str_match_all(rawHTML, '\\d{2} \\w+ 2018'))
```